# Create view using stored procedure Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a list of people and I want to create view for each person.
If I Have 1 person, my view would be:

```
CREATE VIEW PersonInfo AS (
    SELECT * FROM People WHERE id = 1000
);
```

But in fact, I have thousands of people, I want to create a stored procedure in **Oracle** to create view for each person, But View names are duplicated when I use it. How can I handle that problem?
Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: One has to seriously question the basic premise - the need to create a separate view for each person.  What business requirement drives you to this "solution"?  This has all the earmarks of a typical [x-y question](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: What do you mean by "person"? Is it an Oracle user?

Answer (score 4):

Your aim is interesting(*presumably a related with training but not a real-world scenario*), but a dynamic solution would be handled with a for loop by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` of PL/SQL such as

```sql
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Crt_People_Views AS 
BEGIN
 FOR p IN ( SELECT id FROM People )
 LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PersonInfo_'||p.id
                   ||' AS SELECT * FROM People WHERE id = '||p.id;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
SQL> EXEC Crt_People_Views; -- call the proc. which will create the desired views
```

Answer (score -1):

What problem are you trying to solve by creating a view for every person?

Would it make more sense to create a single view that takes a parameter (person_id)?

Something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_ABC (parm1 INTEGER) AS
  SELECT *
  FROM   XYZ
  WHERE ….

Call like this.

Then, all we need do is,
SELECT *
FROM   VIEW_ABC (101)
/
```

No probs. with bind variables. Nicely integrated as one would expect.

Comment: I don't believe that's valid syntax.  Views can't have parameters (there is nothing in the 21c `create view` syntax diagram about parameters https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504).  Perhaps you're thinking of a pipelined table function that takes a parameter?